# Drywall: Removing old mirror and installing new one

Tags: drywall, walls, painting, paint

We are ripping off an old condo mirror from the 1970s, and laying on a new mirror of the exact same size.

Below is a picture of old glue circles, and wall behind it. Before installing the new mirror, should we do any precautionary steps like sanding or putting on compound? My constructor manager says, no one really cares, or will see it since we're putting on a new mirror.

Just wanted to make sure.

[image]
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your picture, no prep needed. If you have any flappy bits of drywall paper, you should remove those.

Make sure you use mirror mastic. Standard construction adhesive can eat through the protective layer on the back of the mirror and damage the reflective surface.

Comment: yeah, just trying to remove the flabby bits of cardboard from the old dry wall, thanks

Comment: New stuff(glue, caulk) on top of old stuff is not recommended, so move the move the new glue spots down or up an inch.

Comment: Make sure you use mirror mastic. Standard construction adhesive can eat through the protective layer on the back of the mirror and damage the reflective surface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sanding and putting on compound will certainly help mounting new mirror, on even surface. Specially if the new mirror is to be glued on.